# Managing packages with Yarn

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

I need to update old dependencies because of security reasons in a project, that uses Yarn and I would like to know the best way to do this. I have used yarn add package-name@latest and yarn upgrade package-name@latest with the same result. The old version package definition remains. Is that acceptable? Since I have to update the old version for security, I think the old version should be removed. Is there a command that updates a package to a specific version and removes the old package definition?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you are describing should only arise if you also have transitive dependencies that come from other dependencies.
So you may have another package that depends on `acorn` in a lower version.

If this is not the case I would try:

```
yarn upgrade package-name --latest
```

To update all packages to the latest versions, I recommend:

```
yarn upgrade-interactive --latest
```